# CouchDB _changes API gets much slower as time goes by

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, couchdb, logstash

CouchDB-1.6.1, database is about 33 million documents.

I am pulling data out of a CouchDB database in 3 ways:

- using the ElasticSearch River plugin (data goes into ElasticSearch-1.x)
- using the Logstash couchdb_changes input plugin (data goes into ElasticSearch-1.x or 2.x)
- using CouchDB-to-CouchDB replication (data goes into CouchDB - used only for comparison and speed tests)

All 3 use the _changes API in Couch as the data source. All three start out very fast - at least thousands of documents per second get copied initially. But then they all slow down.

After about 20 million documents get copied, River slows down to about 20 documents / second. Logstash is about the same.

Couch-2-couch replication also slows down, but in this case I can make it go much faster by increasing parallelism (number of connections and batch size), and so eventually it finishes quick enough:

`"http_connections": 200, "worker_processes": 40, "worker_batch_size": 1000`

But with River and Logstash, there's no way to do that. With River I can at least increase the batch size, but still it only uses 1 connection to Couch.

`"max_concurrent_bulk" : 1000,
        "bulk_size" : "10000",
        "bulk_timeout" : "1000ms"`

The problem is, with a large database, the total time to absorb it in ElasticSearch is on the order of days, or maybe a week, and because speed keeps decreasing all the time, there's the concern that it will eventually be unable to keep up. The speed is almost exactly proportional with 1/x, where x is the number of documents imported so far.

The bottleneck is not on the ElasticSearch side (the destination); ES has enough memory, and CPU usage eventually goes down to near zero. The bottleneck is on Couch (the source); there's one process or thread there which is at 100% CPU usage for the whole duration of the process. But the CouchDB instance with all the source data has lots of CPU cores and is otherwise idle, so it seems like there's something single-threaded about the _changes API.

Is there anything I could do to speed up the process of importing data from CouchDB into ElasticSearch?

Comment: @smathy - I'm doing thorough compaction every week-end, seems to have no impact on _changes. Even general performance changes seem minimal or zero after compaction.

Comment: Using Logstash, have you tried playing with the `-w` [command-line flag](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/command-line-flags.html) or are you using the default? Also, it might be worth [profiling Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/pipeline.html#_profiling_the_heap) in order to see where it itches during the load.

Comment: @Val - the bottleneck is not on the receiving side. Logstash and ElasticSearch run on the same instance, and it's almost idle. The bottleneck is on the sender side - there's exactly 1 thread or process on CouchDB which is pegged at 100% CPU for the entire duration.